# 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'generate_training_data'

Tags: nltk, word2vec

Code :

```
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
w2v = Word2Vec()
training_data = w2v.generate_training_data(settings, corpus)
```

Error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-bae554564046> in <module>
      1 w2v = Word2Vec()
      2 # Numpy ndarray with one-hot representation for [target_word, context_words]
----> 3 training_data = w2v.generate_training_data(settings, corpus)

AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'generate_training_data'
```

I even tried importing gensim.models.word2vec and tried every possibility but couldn't get it done. 
Can someone help me with it?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `gensim` `Word2Vec` class doesn't have that method – and as far as I know, it never has.

And from your example usage, I'm not even sure what it might purport to do: a `Word2Vec` model needs to be provided data in the right format – it doesn't "generate" it (even as a translation from some other corpus).

I suspect you are looking at docs or a code example from some other unrelated library.

For using `gensim`'s `Word2Vec`, you should rely on the `gensim` documentation & examples. The [class docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) include some basic details of proper usage, and there's a Jupyter notebook `word2vec.ipynb` included with the library, in its `docs/notebooks` directory (and also [viewable online](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/word2vec.ipynb)).